# Save an aspx page as PDF on Server

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, pdf

**Background:**

I'm creating `aspx` pages that I'm able to save as PDF's using the following `JavaScript` function:  `window.print();`

This brings up the printer option and I can choose to `Save As PDF`.

**Next Step:**

I would like to save the PDF's that I generate on the the database.

**Problem:**

I don't know how to save my page as a PDF so that it can be accessed on my code behind.

**Question:**

Is there anyone way I can solve my problem using JavaScript/JQuery to send it to the back-end or do straight up do it on the back-end?

**Note:**

If you refer me to a 3rd party library to do it on the back-end, please explain with an example showing how I could convert the entire page (which links to CSS files) to a pdf just like I would be able to see in the above mentioned Background.  Everything I've tried so far leaves me with PDF incorrectly laid out.

Thank you!

Comment: You won't be able to do this in JavaScript--you'll need to do it server-side.

Comment: As mentioned, I'm prepared to do it server side.  I just need a way to do the whole page.

Comment: Is the page content populated using dynamically?

Comment: If you mean it has asp controls then yes?

Comment: No, I mean that a part of the page is generated with JavaScript.

Comment: please also mention what things you have tries so far

Comment: Oh, no nothing is generated with JavaScript.  There's some noPrint CSS but no JS

Comment: Ok, that excludes using PhantomJS (headless browsers) and leave you with many answers on this network. Too many answers to leave in a comment. On a side note, there are free public APIs that I have used, but I am cannot tell if they respect `@print` CSS query. [Convert HTML + CSS to PDF with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/391005/2151050)

Comment: I'm not using PHP though